# Formula to sum columns on Pascal's triangle

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am looking for a general formula for the sum of columns on Pascal's triangle (finite terms), i.e. $$\sum_{k=0}^{k=n} {k+d \choose k}$$

Comment: Use [this link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_r%2Bk_Choose_k_up_to_n)

Comment: [hockeystick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).